# Unexpected Response 400 and 500 in volley with gson post method

Tags: android, post, gson, android-volley

i am repeatedly getting this **Unexpected response code 500 and 400.**
Please help

GsonRequest Class

public class GsonRequest extends Request

{

private Gson mGson = new Gson();

private Class clazz;

private Map headers;

```
private Map<String, String> params;
private Listener<T> listener;
//String mRequestBody;
Map<String, String> mRequestBody;

/**
 * Make a GET request and return a parsed object from JSON.
 *
 * @param url URL of the request to make
 * @param clazz Relevant class object, for Gson's reflection
 */
public GsonRequest(int method,
                   String url,
                   Class<T> clazz,
                   Listener<T> listener,
                   ErrorListener errorListener) {
    super(method, url, errorListener);
    this.clazz = clazz;
    this.listener = listener;
    mGson = new Gson();
}

/**
 * Make a POST request and return a parsed object from JSON.
 *
 * @param url URL of the request to make
 * @param clazz Relevant class object, for Gson's reflection
 */
public GsonRequest(int method,
                   String url,
                   Class<T> clazz,
                   Map<String, String> headers,
                   Map<String, String> requestBody,
                   //String requestBody,
                   Listener<T> listener,
                   ErrorListener errorListener) {

    super(method, url, errorListener);
    //this.mRequestBody = requestBody;
   this.params = requestBody;
    this.listener = listener;
    this.headers = headers;
    mGson = new Gson();
}

@Override
public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {
    return (headers != null) ? headers : super.getHeaders();
}

@Override
public String getBodyContentType() {
    return "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
}


@Override`protected void deliverResponse(T response) {
    listener.onResponse(response);
}


@Override
protected Response<T> parseNetworkResponse(NetworkResponse response) {
    try {
        String json = new String(
                response.data, HttpHeaderParser.parseCharset(response.headers));
        return Response.success(
                mGson.fromJson(json, clazz), HttpHeaderParser.parseCacheHeaders(response));
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        return Response.error(new ParseError(e));
    } catch (JsonSyntaxException e) {
        return Response.error(new ParseError(e));
    }
}
```

}

My activity class

public class Act_GsonRequest extends Activity {
    private TextView mTvResult;

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.act__gson_request);

    mTvResult = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv_result);

    Button btnSimpleRequest = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_gson_request);
    btnSimpleRequest.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            RequestQueue queue=Volley.newRequestQueue(Act_GsonRequest.this);
            Map<String, String> stringMap = new HashMap<>();
            stringMap.put("from", "Kathmandu");
            stringMap.put("to", "Kakadvitta");
            stringMap.put("date", "2015-12-20");
            Log.e("Request body :::::", stringMap.toString());


            HashMap<String, String> headers = new HashMap<String, String>();
            headers.put("Content-Type", "application/json");
            headers.put("Authorization", "Basic YWRtaW46YWRtaW4=");
            headers.put("user", "admin");
            Log.e("Headers :::::", headers.toString());


            GsonRequest<MyClass1> req = new GsonRequest(
                    Method.POST,
                    "http://192.168.0.112:8080/customer/webresources/generic/trips",
                   MyClass1.class,
                    headers,
                    stringMap,
                    createMyReqSuccessListener(),
                    createMyReqErrorListener());


            queue.add(req);




        };

        });
}

private String buildRequestBody(Object content) {
    String output = null;
    if ((content instanceof String) ||
            (content instanceof JSONObject) ||
            (content instanceof JSONArray)) {
        output = content.toString();
    } else if (content instanceof Map) {
        Uri.Builder builder = new Uri.Builder();
        HashMap hashMap = (HashMap) content;
        if (hashMap != null) {
            Iterator entries = hashMap.entrySet().iterator();
            while (entries.hasNext()) {
                Map.Entry entry = (Map.Entry) entries.next();
                builder.appendQueryParameter(entry.getKey().toString(), entry.getValue().toString());
                entries.remove();
            }
            output = builder.build().getEncodedQuery();
        }
    }

    return output;
}
private Response.Listener<MyClass1> createMyReqSuccessListener() {
    return new Response.Listener<MyClass1>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(MyClass1 response) {
           Log.e("Response message",response.getStatus());
        }
    };
}


private Response.ErrorListener createMyReqErrorListener() {
    return new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            mTvResult.setText(error.getMessage());
            NetworkResponse networkResponse = error.networkResponse;
            if (networkResponse != null) {
                Log.e("Volley", "Error. HTTP Status Code:"+networkResponse.statusCode);
            }
            if (error instanceof TimeoutError) {
                Log.e("Volley", "TimeoutError");
            }else if(error instanceof NoConnectionError){
                Log.e("Volley", "NoConnectionError");
            } else if (error instanceof AuthFailureError) {
                Log.e("Volley", "AuthFailureError");
            } else if (error instanceof ServerError) {
                Log.e("Volley", "ServerError");
            } else if (error instanceof NetworkError) {
                Log.e("Volley", "NetworkError");
            } else if (error instanceof ParseError) {
                Log.e("Volley", "ParseError");
            }
        }
    };
}
```

}

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. This question does not state where it's failing or what you've tried to fix the issue you are having.

Comment: it works fine with json but when i tried to make call with gson. It gives me unexpected error 400 (mostly). I dont know whats wrong with the code above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

after using jsonObject instead of hashmap and commiting some alteration in the **GsonRequest** class, I have succesfully solved the issue. 
Anyways thanx guys for your response
Happy coding :)

//Inside activity from where the api call is performed

```
                String url = "http://www.esewa.com/register/new";

                RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(SignUpActivity.this);
                JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();
                try {
                    jsonObject.put("some_key1", "some_value1");
```

jsonObject.put("some_key2", "some_value2");

```
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                Log.d("Request bodyJson:::::", jsonObject.toString());

                HashMap<String, String> headers = new HashMap<String, String>();
                headers.put("Content-Type", "application/json");
                Log.d("Headers :::::", headers.toString());
```

GsonRequest req = new GsonRequest(
                            Request.Method.POST,
                            url,
                            ResponseClass.class,
                            headers,
                            jsonObject,
                            createMyReqSuccessListener(),
                            Utility.createMyReqErrorListener(coordinatorLayout,progressDialog,TAG))

//GsonRequest Class

public class GsonRequest extends Request {

```
private Gson gson = new Gson();
private Class<T> clazz;
private Map<String, String> headers;
private Map<String, String> params;
private Listener<T> listener;
JSONObject jsonObject=null;

/**
 * Make a GET request and return a parsed object from JSON.
 *
 * @param url URL of the request to make
 * @param clazz Relevant class object, for Gson's reflection
 */
public GsonRequest(int method,
                   String url,
                   Class<T> clazz,
                   Listener<T> listener,
                   ErrorListener errorListener) {
    super(method, url, errorListener);
    this.clazz = clazz;
    this.listener = listener;
    gson = new Gson();
}

/**
 * Make a POST request and return a parsed object from JSON.
 *
 * @param url URL of the request to make
 * @param clazz Relevant class object, for Gson's reflection
 */
public GsonRequest(int method,
                   String url,
                   Class<T> clazz,
                   Map<String, String> headers,
                   JSONObject jsonObject,
                   Listener<T> listener,
                   ErrorListener errorListener) {

    super(method, url, errorListener);
    this.jsonObject = jsonObject;
    this.listener = listener;
    this.clazz = clazz;
    this.headers = headers;
    gson = new Gson();
}

@Override
public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {
    return (headers != null) ? headers : super.getHeaders();
}

@Override
public String getBodyContentType() {
    return "application/json; charset=utf-8";
}

@Override
protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {
    return params;
}
```

**//Added this getBody() method**

```
@Override
public byte[] getBody() throws AuthFailureError {
    try {
        return jsonObject.toString().getBytes(getParamsEncoding());
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {

    }
    return null;
}

@Override
protected void deliverResponse(T response) {
    listener.onResponse(response);
}

@Override
protected Response<T> parseNetworkResponse(NetworkResponse networkResponse) {
    try {
        String jsonString = new String(networkResponse.data, HttpHeaderParser.parseCharset(networkResponse.headers));
        T response = new GsonBuilder().create().fromJson(jsonString, clazz);
        //clazz.getClass()
        com.android.volley.Response<T> result = com.android.volley.Response.success(response,
                HttpHeaderParser.parseCacheHeaders(networkResponse));
        return result;
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        return com.android.volley.Response.error(new ParseError(e));
    } catch (JsonSyntaxException e) {
        return com.android.volley.Response.error(new ParseError(e));
    }




}

@Override
protected VolleyError parseNetworkError(VolleyError volleyError){
    if(volleyError.networkResponse != null && volleyError.networkResponse.data != null){
        VolleyError error = new VolleyError(new String(volleyError.networkResponse.data));
        AppLog.showLog("Inside parseNetworkError::::::::: ");
        volleyError = error;
    }

    return volleyError;
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

If its due to slow internet connection change the RetryPolicy. Simply set the timeout value to double of the default timeout. Worked fine.add this before       `queue.add(req);`

```
  req.setRetryPolicy(new DefaultRetryPolicy(DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_TIMEOUT_MS * 2, DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_MAX_RETRIES, DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_BACKOFF_MULT));
  queue.add(req);
```